# What algorithm can be used to rate resumes?

Tags: algorithm, automation, resume

What algorithm can I use to rate different resumes so as to facilitate easy picking of the best resume?

Comment: Can you clearify? There is not "algorithm" able to do this, the closest I can imagine would be using machine learning with tons of resumes as training data where you had classified which ones were good beforehand. What is it that you are looking for?

Comment: Also notice that this is a highly biased task; since you basically have no feedback on "false negatives" (i.e. candidates that you reject but would have been a great fit), you cannot really optimize a model to perform really well. Although that's a general problem of HR, not just machine learning models, you should be aware what implications the automation might have.

Answer (score 1):

There are ATS systems like [Taleo](https://www.oracle.com/uk/applications/taleo.html) which rank resumes based on keywords. E.g. if an employer is looking for sales experience, they can find resumes which are most suited to them if 'Sales' is listed in the job titles. Similarly, you have sites like [Resume Worded](https://resumeworded.com/) which ranks resumes based on their style, impact and brevity, and gives an overall [resume score](https://resumeworded.com/). They take a more machine learning/AI driven approach, and have trained their resume scorer over a bunch of good resume examples. It really depends on the factors you want to rank your resume on.